# why include() don't allow to work setcookie?

Tags: php

i need to set cookies in my page, but it returns

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home1/bsam/public_html/24kadr/index.php:1) in /home1/bsam/public_html/24kadr/basic_login.php  on line 35
```

on line 1 i have

```
include 'basic_login.php';
```

but even if i remoove include, ir returns the same warning on session_start, or mysql_connect.
so i think these all functions use header when calling, but what can i do? at least i need to connect to database, and just after it i need to use setcookie().
so what can i do?
thanks

### update the first lines of index.php

```
<?include 'basic_login.php';include 'settings.php';?>
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
...........
```

in basic_login.php it starts

```
<?
session_start();
include 'connect.php';
ini_set("session.bug_compat_42",1);
ini_set("session.bug_compat_warn",0);
```

..........................................

```
setcookie("cookname", $_SESSION['username'], time()+60*60*24*30, "/");
setcookie("cookpass", $_SESSION['password'], time()+60*60*24*30, "/");
```

---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You most likely have white space in `/24kadr/index.php` before the opening `<?php`. Remove it and it should be fine.

If there is no white space, maybe your PHP file was saved with a [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM). In that case, have your editor save the file without it.

Comment: @Pekka i've remoove ti, but it doesn' help:(

Comment: Can you show the first lines of /24kadr/index.php?

Comment: @Pekka i've shown. look please

Comment: @Syom maybe the file has a BOM. See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814258/bom-in-a-php-page-auto-generated-by-wordpress on how to remove it.

Comment: @Syom and it's still the exact same error message, right?

Answer (score 2):

You get this error if you output *anything* before the header/cookie is set. Either do it before you output anything, even blank lines, or use [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams so when i call include(), it is outputing?
what is output buffering, i don't know:(

Comment: Some file you're using somewhere outputs something. Check your files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your file */24kadr/index.php* begins with

```
<?php
```

with not a single character before then you may be hitting the "UTF-8 with BOM" issue

If your editor is configured to save file with encoding "UTF-8 with BOM" then it will add (and not show) 2 special characters at the beginning of your file.

This can lead PHP to throw the warning.

I hope this will help
Jerome WAGNER